# Why can't activated grown brain of Lucy control itself to some percentage?

Tags: lucy

In Lucy as CPH4 comes in contact with Lucy blood and she begins acquiring increasingly enhanced physical and mental capabilities, such as telepathy, telekinesis, mental time travel, and the ability not to feel pain or other discomforts. It is because her brain starts activating to 100%. As it is also said that when brain reaches 20% of its power remaining 80% starts activating automatically.

My question is as she can control pain, color of her hair, also some non living things like phone, TV etc, Why is it that a 100% activated brain can't control itself? I mean it can be controlled to 20% not more than that.

Comment: I'm tempted to say she can't control the fundamental laws of physics, in this case, conservation of energy. She can't stop the energy of CPH4 from existing.

Comment: @cde Unless she has a metabolism that burns through thousands of calories per minute and somehow uses that, I'm fairly sure any type of telepathy from seemingly nowhere is breaking conservation of energy.

Comment: @sgr what makes you think telepathy requires that much energy? If it's using existing parts of the brain... and we are literally told that CPH4 has the energy of an atomic bomb.

Comment: a 100% activated brain doesnt need body... It is very in control of the consciousness.

Comment: I'm guessing the OP asks for the reasoning behind this in the film (or as explained by the creator/director) - I don't see any reason to assume otherwise. VTLO.